# Getting a strings value from string.prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Hi so I'm  trying to learn a little more about prototyping and javascript and so lets say I have this code

```
String.prototype.getVal=function() 
{
    return ?
};
```

How would a string so that `'Spencer'.getVal()==='Spencer'` would I have to use this within the function and then iterate over each character in the object?

Comment: I just realized in the console theres a member: `[[PrimitiveValue]]` can I use that somehow?

Comment: Are you looking for [`.valueOf()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.3)?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe this answer can explain what prototype is, what it's used for, what `this` is and what it's used for and the difference between them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 If you have any questions about it please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is pointless but

```
String.prototype.getVal = function() { return this.toString(); };
```

It's pointless because you can just use `.toString()` directly.

```
alert( new String("pointless").toString() === "pointless" ); // true
```

or

```
alert( String( new String("pointless") ) === "pointless" ); // also true
```

The `String` constructor, when invoked without `new`, basically returns the `.toString()` value of its argument if it's an object.

Comment: @RCV there's a difference between the primitive type `string` and the object type `String`.

Comment: I'm aware that its pointless, as I mentioned; the question was for learning purposes and to be used in practical applications, which I dont have the time to think up for rude people

Comment: @user1895629 you didn't actually mention it, and this isn't a "rude" answer. It's just a factual observation. Insulting people who've taken the trouble to answer a question you've asked is a curious thing to do.